# How to test a function of a solidity that used time to operate

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, nodejs, hardhat

I've written a contract function that stakes tokens after every one minute of the previous stake, on user input. The code goes like this...

```
uint public pastStakeTime = block.timestamp;

function stakeToken(uint _amount, address _staker) external payable {
        require(block.timestamp - pastStakeTime > 1 minutes, "please wait for 1 minutes");
        //as a record that this stakeholder staked this amount
        stakeholderBalance[_staker] += _amount;
        //all the amounts must have the authority of admin
        entityBalances[admin_HolderOfTokens] += _amount;
        //pushing the stakeholder in our stake holder address
        stakeHolder.push(_staker);
        pastStakeTime = block.timestamp;
    }
```

Now, I'm testing it using node.js setTimeout() like this...

```
it('it stakes the tokens at the right time', async () => {
        const stakeAmount = 500;
        setTimeout(await token.stakeToken, 120000, stakeAmount, stakeHolder.address);
        //await token.stakeToken(stakeAmount, stakeHolder.address);
        console.log(await token.getStakeHolderBalance(stakeHolder.address));
    });

setTimeout(await token.stakeToken, 120000, stakeAmount, stakeHolder.address);
```

but when I'm testing it ...

```
console.log(await token.getStakeHolderBalance(stakeHolder.address)); produces 0 and in remix, it produces the right output.
```

Anyone, please help.

Comment: check this https://medium.com/sablier/writing-accurate-time-dependent-truffle-tests-8febc827acb5

Comment: Can I get ways for Hardhat?

Comment: is your question for hardhat or truffle?

Comment: whoops, I added the tag of truffle rather than hardhat sorry!

Comment: await ethers.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [120]); 120=>two mins in seconds. 

I found the solution hallelujah!

Answer (score 3):

In Tests you can use `@openzeppelin/test-helpers` ([link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers)) to change the time of the local blockchain like ganache and hardhat

```
 const { time } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
  ...
  ..
  .
 it('test something', async () => {
   // do something before
     await time.increase(time.duration. minutes(2)); // change time
   // do something after
 });
```

If you are using hardhat and want to change the time every now and then manually (maybe to test on remix or in the console) you can try write a task to manipulate the time, example:

```
task('increaseMinutes', 'Increase minutes')
  .addParam('mins', 'The number of minutes').setAction(
    async (taskArguments) => {
      const blockBeforeTimeChange = await network.provider.send('eth_getBlockByNumber', ['latest', false]);
      console.log('Timestamp before change', blockBeforeTimeChange.timestamp, new Date(blockBeforeTimeChange.timestamp * 1000));
      await network.provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [60 * Number(taskArguments.mins)]);
      await network.provider.send('evm_mine');
      const blockAfterTimeChange = await network.provider.send('eth_getBlockByNumber', ['latest', false]);
      console.log('Timestamp after change', blockAfterTimeChange.timestamp, new Date(blockAfterTimeChange.timestamp * 1000));
      return true;
    });
```

to run a task

```
npx hardhat --network <your-network> increaseMinutes --mins <number-of-minutes>
```

Comment: I tried the time.duration.minutes(2) method but it is still not executing the function.

Comment: can you see in the console if the block time changed?, if yes then you need to debug the code again and see what is wrong . i think this does not work setTimeout(await token.stakeToken, 120000, stakeAmount, stakeHolder.address); what are you trying to do?

Comment: Again telling, I made a function which is mentioned above that stakes tokens again after one minute of the previous staking, on user input. Now, I have to test it, and the test code, I've also mentioned above.

Comment: sorry i had no time to fix my answer (therefore i hided it temporary) .. I updated it -> ( await time.increase(time.duration.days(2));). The 'await time.increase' was missing @AdilNehal